# PHP Laravel: Использование класса из библиотеки в контроллере

Tags: php, laravel

Установлил библиотеку mongo, написал тестовый скрипт по примеру:

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('atms');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'atms');

$q = array();

$cursor = $collection->find($q);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}
```

Запускаю:

```
$ php test.php
```

Выводит содержимое коллекции, как и ожидается. Но если сделать то же в контроллере Laravel, то получаю ошибку:

> Class 'App\Classes\MongoClient' not found.

При этом phpinfo(), вызванный из контроллера, содержит библиотеку mongo. Хочу сделать простой запрос используя стандартную библиотеку для работы с MongoDB без установки компонентов для Laravel. Как объяснить что нужно использовать стандартный класс из библиотеки? Или дело в чем-то еще...?

Comment: Нужно было добавить "\" перед классом: \MongoClient, \MongoCollection. Понятия не имею почему

Comment: Почитайте про неймспейсы и поймете почему.